# How to change the type of variable into tf.float16 in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a model with all variable defined in fp32, How can I change the datatype of all the variable into fp16?(I can't change the source file of model definition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use post-training quantization technique (to optimize your model, make it run much faster without reducing much accuracy).

With Tensorflow model, you can use TFLite Converter. Here's the link to the guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#float16_quantization